# Set export value of a new created checkbox with iText

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to add a checkbox to an existing pdf. Also I need set the export value of this checkbox. I saw that this should be configurared with appearance dictionary /AP but till now I did evaluate how to set this on a new checkbox.
With export value I mean the value which is marked in the screenshot

[image]

Here is my code which creates a checkbox, but the export value is always empty...

```
case AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
            PdfFormField checkbox = PdfFormField.createCheckBox(stamper.getWriter());
            checkbox.setWidget(fieldVO.rect, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_NONE);
            checkbox.setFieldName(fieldVO.getNewName());
            //TODO set export value
            log.info("exportValue is " + fieldVO.getExportValue());
            stamper.addAnnotation(checkbox, fieldVO.getPageNumber());
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this: you are using `PdfFormField` to create a check box. That is hard. Why don't you use the `RadioCheckField` class?

```
rect = new Rectangle(180, 806, 200, 788);
checkbox = new RadioCheckField(stamper.getWriter(), rect,
     "fieldVO.getNewName()", "on");
field = checkbox.getCheckField();
```

Then you want to define the appearances. Suppose that `onOff` is an array of `PdfAppearance` objects, one with the appearance if the box isn't selected (`0`) and one if the box is selected (`1`). Note that the name of the *off state* should be `"Off"` as defined in ISO-32000-1. As far as I remember, the standard recommends using `"Yes"` for the *on state*, but you can use a custom value, such as `"MyCustomValue"`:

```
field.setAppearance(
    PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "Off", onOff[0]);
field.setAppearance(
    PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, "MyCustomValue", onOff[1]);
```

In this case, the appearance of the *on state* will be stored as an entry with key `/MyCustomValue`. This key is a *PDF name object* and several restrictions apply. That's why the `/Opt` key was introduced:

> (Taken from ISO-32000-1) Beginning with PDF 1.4, the field dictionary for check boxes and radio buttons may contain an optional **Opt** entry. If present, the **Opt** entry shall be an array of text strings representing the export value of each annotation in the field. It may be used for the following purposes:
>
> - To represent the export values of check box and radio button fields in non-Latin writing systems. Because name objects in the appearance dictionary are limited to PDFDocEncoding, they cannot represent non-Latin text.
> - To allow radio buttons or check boxes to be checked independently, even if they have the same export value.
>
> EXAMPLE: a group of check boxes may be duplicated on more than one page such that the desired behavior is that when a user checks a box, the corresponding boxes on each of the other pages are also checked. In this case, each of the corresponding check boxes is a widget in the Kids array of a check box field.

In your case, you'd need something like:

```
PdfArray options = new PdfArray();
options.add(new PdfString("My Custom Value"));
field.put(PdfName.OPT, options);
```

I haven't tested if this works, I'm merely interpreting what ISO-32000-1 says and converting the spec into iText code.

Finally, you can add the field.

```
stamper.addAnnotation(field, 1);
```